# Best replacement for Reflections in C# .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-4.0, delegates

I am faced with following code for retrieving data through reflections:

```
public object GetValue(object source)
{
    if (Member == null) return Argument;
    try
    {
        object[] argList = (Argument == null ? null : new object[] { Argument });
        if (Member is PropertyInfo) return ((PropertyInfo)Member).GetValue(source, argList);
        if (Member is MethodInfo) return ((MethodInfo)Member).Invoke(source, argList);
        if (Member is FieldInfo) return ((FieldInfo)Member).GetValue(source);
        throw new Exception("Unknown member type: " + Member);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not get value " + Member.Name + " from " + source + " with " + Argument, ex);
    }
}
```

This is however very slow, and I am thinking of replacing the reflections with something faster, maybe delegates? However, I am not sure that delegates is the best choice or how to implement it in this case. I am running .NET 4.0. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: is there are a possibility to use typed `source` parameter? Or generalize all object passed here via interface?

Comment: `Argument` and `Member` are semi-fixed or they change very often? Because `GetValue` has a single parameter.

Comment: You have .net 4.0, i don't know the scope of your application, but why not try moving to DLR if you have very reflection heavy code?

Comment: @Vivek, thanks for the suggestion. The project is large and complex, so maybe it will be too much work, but I will look into it.

Comment: @xanatos, every call to fetch data from server goes through this function, so it is normally thousands of calls. I assume this means they both change a lot, but I can look into it when at work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little faster

```
static Func<object, object[], object> BuildCaller(MethodInfo method)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var pars = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    var pars2 = method.GetParameters();

    var casted = new Expression[pars2.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < pars2.Length; i++)
    {
        casted[i] = Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayAccess(pars, Expression.Constant(i)), pars2[i].ParameterType);
    }

    var call = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(obj, method.DeclaringType), method, casted);
    var cast = Expression.Convert(call, typeof(object));
    var lamdba = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[], object>>(cast, obj, pars);
    return lamdba.Compile();
}

static Func<object, object[], object> BuildCaller(FieldInfo field)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var pars = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    var call = Expression.Field(Expression.Convert(obj, field.DeclaringType), field);
    var cast = Expression.Convert(call, typeof(object));
    var lamdba = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[], object>>(cast, obj, pars);
    return lamdba.Compile();
}

static Func<object, object[], object> BuildCaller(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var pars = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    var pars2 = property.GetIndexParameters();

    var casted = new Expression[pars2.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < pars2.Length; i++)
    {
        casted[i] = Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayAccess(pars, Expression.Constant(i)), pars2[i].ParameterType);
    }

    var call = Expression.Property(Expression.Convert(obj, property.DeclaringType), property, casted);
    var cast = Expression.Convert(call, typeof(object));
    var lamdba = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object[], object>>(cast, obj, pars);
    return lamdba.Compile();
}
```

I create a delegate (through `Expression`s) that precaches the method. If `Arguments` are "fixed" you could go a step further and precache even their conversion (as is the conversion is done each time the method is called)

This is an example for methods. For properties and fields it's similar (for fields it's even easier).

And an example of use

```
var fun = BuildCaller(typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod"));
var mc = new MyClass();
fun(mc, new object[] { 1, 2.0 });
```

You must cache `fun` together with your `Method`